# Get C# type from file name

Tags: c#

I have a bunch of files in a directory:

**Class1.ascx** : contains class Class1
**Class2.ascx** : contains class Class2

I have a list of the file names, and I want to take each filename and identify the corresponding class.

```
foreach(var fileName in listOfFileNames)
{
   ...
   Type t = MagicMethod(fileName)
   ...
}
```

Anyone know what MagicMethod would look like or if it is even possible to do?

Comment: A file could easily contain more than one class. Not a recommended practice, but it is allowed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The filename could be different than the classname.  The file may not even contain a class.

You would have to parse the file.

[Here is a parser on codeplex](http://www.codeplex.com/csparser).

Comment: In this case we can assume that class names and filenames are identical.  Its a good point for a more general case though.